# jQuery - Get Title Attribute from IMG tag

Tags: jquery, click, image, title

I have a list of IMG tags with different TITLE attributes as provided below.

```
<img src="avatar1.png" title="Admin" height="90px" width="90px" />  
<img src="avatar2.png" title="Purus" height="90px" width="90px" />  
<img src="avatar3.png" title="Test" height="90px" width="90px" />
```

I am trying to get the TITLE attribute of the IMG tag when the user click on the image. Below is the jQuery I have used.

```
$('img').click(function(){  
    alert($(this).attr('title'));  
});
```

With this code I get the alert as "Undefined". I tried to search already and any solution did not help me. Where I am going wrong here?

PS: This is my first question over here. So advice if I am doing anything wrong in this post.

Comment: [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/ZX98T/)

Comment: Did you remember document.ready and to include jQuery ?

Comment: your code seems to be correct... and in fact it works for me...

Comment: I have included jquery. Thanks @Bruno for testing this. But it does not work for me. I have many other IMG tags apart from these. Is that a reason?

Comment: Are your images overlapping each other? Console log `this`, to make sure you're getting the image you think you clicked on.

Comment: @Jack : I inspected the "this" object using "Watch" in Firebug and it shows all attributes except the title attribute.. but it exists in the html code.

Comment: Try adding a title attribute to every image, or temporarily remove images that don't have them. Then see if you always get a title returned. If you get the title after that then you must have some other issue that isn't apparent.

Comment: As you suggested I tried but with a small change. I tried adding a new attribute "name" to these 3 images and made alert for $(this).attr('name') and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add a new attribute called "Name" to these 3 IMG tags and used the below code to achive what I needed. Thanks for all your help on this.

```
$(this).attr('name')
```

Comment: I have encountered the same problem you have described here...seems to be identical to everything you have mentioned. The trick with using the attribute name also worked. Interestingly, for my site I noticed that (since my page takes a few seconds to load because it is huge) alert($("#myID").attr("title")) DOES work and alerts the title attribute BEFORE the page is fully loaded, but once the page is fully loaded it then alerts "undefined"....any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** This answer is based on what you had initially, `$(this).title` - I believe you have updated it with `$(this).attr('title')` which should work fine as is. Still below is the recommended way to access `title`.

---

Just do `alert(this.title);`  No need jQuery for this.

`this` inside the click function is the img element. It has attributes such as src, title, height, width, e.t.c.

To access those attributes, simply use the `this` object as `this.src` to get the src attribute value, `this.title` to get the title and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. When I try this, I just get an empty alert box.

Comment: The HTML has other IMG tags too. Is that the reason? I want to get the title for the Image which has been clicked. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Purus Make sure the image you're clicking has a title attribute.

Comment: @Jack: Yes. It has the title attribute. But there are many other IMG tags which does not title attribute which I don't want to consider for my process.

Answer (score 1):

Its working, Please check this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rahulJs/WEeme/)

```
$('img').click(function(){  
    alert($(this).attr('title'));  
});
```

Comment: I dont think so, are u enclosing your code in $(document).ready(function() { /*your code*/ }) ?

Comment: I have this within the ready function... as I have other part of the jquery working.